# How to apply an effect on TImage?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

[This tutorial](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_FireMonkey_Image_Effects) says that in order to apply an effect to an image, you need to make the effect a child of the `MultiResBitmap` of that image:

[image]

I can't do that. The effect refuses to nest under `MultiResBitmap`. It remains stuck under `Image1`:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? This should be so simple....

Why does the `MultiResBitmap` contain the word `'bitmap'`? Does it HAVE to contain a bitmap (BMP), or does it also work with JPG?

---

I am new to Delphi 10.2 Tokyo (and FMX) - I am trialing it for a possible purchase.

Comment: Did you try to drop `effect` item into `TImage`? It will show you preview in Design mode. Be sure that your effect is perfectly fit and inner item of your target item.

Comment: Solved! Today, after a computer/Delphi restart, it worked!

Answer (score 3):

I just tested it following the steps in the tutorial, and it works perfectly fine for me. Drag and drop `RippleEffect1` onto `Image1` (not the multi-res bitmap, but `Image1`).

[image: Sample of proper drag and drop operation]

The image does not have to be a bitmap; it can be any supported image type. The name choice you'll have to ask Embarcadero about, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks. I will post my own video. Maybe someone will figure out what I am doing wrong. If I am doing it right, then we have an IDE bug.

Comment: @Ampere: Clearly not an IDE bug, as I demonstrated. I followed the precise steps in the tutorial from the link you posted. You may have found an issue in the trial version, however; if that's the case, you'll need to open a support request at Embarcadero, as no one here can help with that problem.

Comment: I have no steps to reproduce the error (it worked after Delphi restart). So, no way to post a bug - for this specific issue. However, I already reported 3 new issues (IDE crashes) in the Trial version. I intended to purchase Delphi 10.2 as they advertised that MOST bugs were fixed. Looks like SOME bugs were fixed, and a  new other bunch were added :) :(